# How to write a regular expression to get a value between parentheses?

Tags: php, regex

I have large string with many values that are encapsulated with `()` and I need to extract the values between the parentheses. For example:

> 443fhjksd9(DB)adsfkhj

How would I write a regular expression to get just these values? Further to this point, how do I use php to get return these values from a string?

```
$infile = @file_get_contents('output.pdf');
$results = run_expression('EXPRESSION', $infile);
```

Perhaps if the regex nullifies everything but the items within parenthesis, then I could use `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern: `~\(([^)]*)\)~Ui` selects anything within parentheses

then just use `preg_match()` or `preg_match_all()` as you need them

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php